# Where is an element's scrollTop property stored?

Tags: javascript

I have to set the scrollTop property of an element to 0 while it's not visible. As the example shows, the property is always 0 if the element is hidden, but it gets restored when the element is visible again. So where is that value stored?

```css
#container{
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle" onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'none'">hide container</button>
<button id="toggle" onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'block'">show container</button>
<button id="show value" onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('container').scrollTop">show ScrollTop</button>
<div id="result">0</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">scroll down to change the value</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding your "direct" question - it is not stored anywhere, it's just recalculated when it is no more with "display: none".

Comment: @SamuilPetrov The fact that the scroll is preserved when you hide and then show the div implies that the scroll position is indeed stored in some way (I think in a not accesible way).

Comment: If you need to access the last scrollTop value before the container was hidden, a workaround is to attach an scroll event handler and save last value in a variable.

Comment: @raul.villa this is just additional browser behaviour... just try it in IE for example and see that it's not preserving it.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov good to know, thanks!

Comment: @raul.vila Thanks for the workaround! If I showed, measured, then hidden the elements the page would hang rendering them for too long.

Comment: @Nadroev sorry, I don't understand you, this is what I meant: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/7309e0et/

Answer (score 0):

If the element is not displayed it is not in the document. You can not get scrollTop of it because it has none.

If you need to "move it" then I recommend you to add it an style, something like `element.style.top` (It depends in how your HTML is)